# Yii2 Restful api with multiple models in same controller

Tags: yii2

how to implement a multiple models in same controller in Yii2.. need an example of it..eg. in my webserviceController having two models say users and employees. now i need to create a restful api in same controller which can access both models users and employees..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you want directly create object and access it.like below

> $users = new users();
>     $employees = new employees();